# NoMachine NX Client V4 and Lightdm

Tags: gnome, lightdm, remote-desktop

I am trying to connect from an Ubuntu 13.10 laptop with Nomachine nx V4 to an Ubuntu 12.04 system with Nomachine nx V3.5

I can successfully connect to the machine, but if I try to connect to the physical display (described from nomachine as "user lightdm") i receive the error message "The session negotiation failed. Error: Cannot share session of user: lightdm".

I tried to work around this issue by spawning a new session with a gnome virtual desktop: the desktop spawns but as soon as I click anywhere inside the desktop Nomachine crash with no outputs whatsoever, the window simply closes.

Is there a way to make lightdm "open" to nomachine sessions?

Comment: Thank you, it may be helpful as I am having a similar problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again I answer myself for any other one encountering such problems (and for future reference if it happens again to myself! :-) ).

The trick was, for me, to modify some options in the NX server configuration file, which is `/usr/NX/etc/server.cfg`

Here you can find lots of stuff and options like "Allow every user (not only NX user) to have a session" and other options pertaining session shadowing and physical display usage: by enabling those options (allowing any user to use the physical display and "steal it" even without spawning a new session), I was able to solve the "cannot share session with user lightdm".